# Making the android toolbar visible in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am trying to incorporate a toolbar in my app but am having problems with its visibility. I would like to add a toolbar to activity_main.xml which is given by

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/BLACK"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/activity_toolbar"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:id="@+id/OFF"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="150dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ON"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/ON"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="150dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and [image]

I have tried to `<include>` toolbar as was suggested on an online tutorial I found. activity_toolbar.xml is given by,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:visibility="visible">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and [image]

I tried to the set the toolbar's visibility to "true" in order to try and manually make the toolbar show on activity_main.xml, but this makes no difference. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that `Toolbar` has no `BackgroundColor`, it won't show up.

You can use that like this(Toolbar is currently visible but you can't see it):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="OFF"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="150dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ON"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="ON"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="150dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, i'd rather to use `AppCompat` with the Android new design style.that will help you to use these things like `Toolbar` easily.

And this should solve that not displaing title,
**Use it in your OnCreate method:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Comment: The only problem with is that the add name is no longer there. I tried android:title="@string/app_name" but it did not work

Comment: Yeah the name has gone and I cannot get it back

Comment: Yes in the toolbar, it makes no sense why it does not work

Comment: @Jurassic - Answer updated, and you were right about that, i've fixed both xml and java codes.please check it. and it's working now.

Comment: I will check this on my phone now

Comment: That hasnt exactly worked. Its made the load up screen grey, then the first  click it changes to black before proceeding with the usual app. Also I wanted the blue status bar and toolbar combination

Comment: Yeah, well, you need to just change the backgrounds for your porpuse.i think this question has solved by now.goodluck.